# Get base64 data of image inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question is asked man times but my problem is this. I want to get data of image inside a canvas and get that! But when I change the image resource derived data does not change. In an other words it doesn't matter what image I use in my code. For best understanding my question my code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <canvas id="viewport" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('viewport'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            make_base();

            function make_base()
            {
              base_image = new Image();
              base_image.src = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
              base_image.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
              }
            }


            const base64Canvas = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").split(';base64,')[1];
            document.write('<br>');
            document.write(base64Canvas);

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I the code above it does not matter what picture to use. The base64 data is same or every one. Any help?

Comment: JavaScript uses an async network call to load an image; so you need to wait for that call to finish before you try to collect the image info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download image after load it in Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714369/download-image-after-load-it-in-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

you should capture the image after it has been loaded and drawn. this is asynchronous action so:

Update: please use an image locally or from an origin that allows CORS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="viewport" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('viewport'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    make_base();

    function make_base() {
      base_image = new Image();

      base_image.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);

        const base64Canvas = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").split(';base64,')[1];
        console.log(base64Canvas);
      }
      base_image.crossOrigin = "anonymous"

      base_image.src = 'https://picsum.photos/200';

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @goldman I could not properly understand your answer! What should I do what should I change?

Comment: I have moved the saving part into the `onload` part so that image would load first

Comment: BUT this does not show any string for me on the screen! This just shows the image. I am referring to ```document.write(base64Canvas); ```

Comment: this example won't work here because of cross domain issues.

Comment: @goldman I ran your edition in browser in Firefox it just shows image.

Comment: that depends where the image is I guess. now example works

Comment: @goldman Is it possible to exert an if() condition to QUESTIONS ORIGINAL script so that it  execute ```toDataURL()``` after image is completely drawn in canvas? I am waiting for your answer. tnx

Comment: you can't exert if() or return value immediately because it is unknown how much time takes for the image to load. it is **asynchronous** so you only get to know after it loads, if you set `onload` of the image to a function of your choosing. it is on that function you add your logic.